Changes in custom plugin not visible
I am using Shopware 6 and need to adjust a custom plugin that adds a page with a form to the admin area. I only changed the label of an input field (Twig file).
After hours of research, I have tried the following steps:

Switched to Developer Mode in the .env file and disabled cache
Changed the plugin version
Deactivated and reactivated the plugin
Cleared the cache using cache:clear via SSH
Rebuilt the administration using administration:build via SSH

None of these steps have helped.
In the backend, I can see that the environment is in dev mode and the cache is not active. The only thing I still notice is the cache adapter: CacheDecorator (could this possibly have something to do with it?).
Or am I missing a crucial step to make the changes visible in the admin area?
Thank you very much!

Have you tried bin/build-administration.sh?
Usually, rebuilding the administration should do the trick for what you described.
